# Change CSS href link Dynamiclly

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<link href="CSS/make.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This an external css file for a page named `"Default.aspx"` which is located in `"Root/Pages"` directory.

so In `"Root/Pages"` we will have these:

```
Default.aspx
CSS/make.css
```

It will work fine if I launch `Default.aspx` from current location, But user can change the directory of Default.aspx from main page. Then in Code-Behind I will copy all of Pages contents into another directory.

Just think I will copy Default.aspx and CSS folder from `Root/Pages` to `Root/Backup` and try to launch Default.aspx from new location. In this situation it can not read and load external css file!

How can I change css href link dynamically from its container page's location?

For example changing `href="CSS/make.css"` to `href="BackUp/CSS/make.css"`.

After some research I found that I should use Global and URL Routing, but I did not get any working result.

Comment: Have you tried with the "~" such as in "~/BackUp/CSS/make.css" .

Comment: yes I have tried it so. I also tried to add runat="server" property to link tag. it is good but it will fill parent directory with ".." not real name. for example it will make css href from "CSS/make.css" to "../../CSS/make.css", if it replace ".." with real folder names it will work fine.

Comment: Hmm, Server.MapPath("~/BackUp/CSS/make.css")?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the css file in the root directory then refer to it using:

```
<link href="/make.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It should now work even when you move your `Default.aspx` to another location. The downside to this is that it can clutter your root directory if you plan to use it for multiple different pages with different CSS files.

Let me know if it works and if I am understanding your question right.

Comment: I must move CSS/make.css with Default.aspx. It can be copy into several directories and I should not to use a fixed location for css file.

Comment: In that case the above example doesn't work. The only other way I can think of right now is by using `<link href="make.css" rel="stylesheet" />` . This way the CSS file needs to be in the exact same directory that your `default.aspx` file is located in (allows you to move them together as long as they stay in the same directory). Hope you can find a way that works!

Answer (score 0):

```
function DynamicURL()
    {  
    var URL='CSS/make.css';
    var BackUp ='BackUp/';
    if (Your condition when it changes directory)
    URL = Backup + URL;

    document.getElementById('Field').href= URL;
    }
```

Don't forget to set ID to your link href field.